# Which is the physical insight behind the widely approved 'space vector' notation used in the analysis of the dynamic model of electric machines?

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine, winding, magnetic-flux, synchronous-motor

When approaching the study of electric machines in transient condition, it is customary to discard the real physical vector quantities like magnetic field and magnetic induction and to define fake vectors like flux linkages, currents and voltages (among which there also induced electromotive forces) which are directed along the magnetic axis of a certain coil (for instance in a three phase winding system) and have the magnitude equal to the actual scalar value.

I have read that they are not intended exactly as physical vectors, rather as complex numbers, lying on a complex plane which is the shadow of the actual plane defined by a cross section of the machine: for instance the real axis is aligned with the phase 'A' magnetic axis and the other two phases 'B' and 'C' windings correspond to a couple of complex conjugate points; then, such quantities are used, without any particular derivation, as actual vector lying in the cartesian space (for instance the flux has component along two orthogonal axes, usually called \$\alpha, \beta\$ or \$d,q\$).

I perfecly understand, that, in order to simplify the analysis and improve the understanding of a complex system like an electromagnetic device, a certain abstraction, which requires to define also artificial entities, is needed, but I cannot see the reason why such 'abuse of notation' is physically legitimized, in fact I am not sure if it is still an abuse of notation or directly a misuse of notation.

The most confusing situation is the anisotropic (salient pole) rotor used inside synchronous machines, where, for instance, the flux produced by a sinusoidally distributed winding in the stator, linked with another distributed winding (which can be the same phase or another) is simply computed using direct flux and quadrature flux as fluxes produced when the rotor is aligned or in quadrature with that winding.

I think that, when dealing with physical phenomena, before using powerful mathematical tools like these, one should prove that they produce the same result of a strict physical approach (just like when Maxwell equations are replaced by other theoretical tools, like circuit theory or transmission lines, after showing that this is actually possible, not only sought). I hope someone can help me understand this formalism.

EDIT:
In order to better explain the problem, if a winding of a certain phase, no matter what, is distributed along the stator inner periphery, it is accustomed to consider the field it produces as sinusoidal (considering just the first angular harmonic) and the coil distribution can be approximated as sinusoidal as well, centred about the winding magnetic axis. Now to compute the mutual inductance between two stator phases, one should compute the flux linkage of a differential coil (in the angular span between \$\theta\$ and \$\theta +\mathrm{d} \theta\$) produced by the sinusoidal field produced by another winding, then integrate this infinitesimal contribution along all the flat angle, whereas often the problem is roughly solved drawing a flux vector (which is not a vector) and decomposing it along the axes of the other windings, like there were just single loop coil for each phase (non distributed windings).

Comment: Have you studied the development of this type of analysis in more than one textbook? If not, it might help to look at how this is explained by several authors. I have some understanding, but I don't think it is sufficient for me to be able to contribute to the understanding of anyone else. At minimum, several illustrations would be required. It would be better to have a live presentation. You might be able to find a recorded lecture.

Comment: You should read Carver Mead's book on Collective Electrodynamics: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/collective-electrodynamics  Chapter 1~3 will get you fixed up.

Comment: What makes Maxwell's Equations a good foundation?  According to your approach, those first need to be derived from string theory.  (And perhaps we might as well give up altogether until a grand unified theory is worked out)  Engineering models are useful because they align with reality, independently of whether there is an elegant formal description.

Comment: Actually, from your question I can't tell which direction your approach is trying to go... Your first paragraph seems to aim for more measurable less theoretical models, while your last paragraph requires the measurable model to be derived from the foundational theoretical model, which uses the abstract quantities you start out complaining about.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I have carried out research far and wide in order to improve my understanding of such a theory; I also have read technical papers in which contemporary engineers and scientists dealing with electric machinery, discuss the fact that this theory, developed in particular by two scholars from the past (I can't remember their names, I will report them as soon as I manage to find such papers again) was very powerful in its intrinsic speculation but eventually failed to prove itself a natural abstraction, then it was good, but essentially 'oddly stilted'.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Of course I have developed an alternative analysis, basing on a solid physical background, but I still would like to understand why this approach has been widely approved by the world engineering community. If you have some author in mind, I will try to trace their books so that the problem is addressed using common clearer references.

Comment: @bdegnan I am going to try to consult the book you proposed, but I have to ask, is it something related to epistemology and philosophy of science? I hope not, since I am not interested in arguing about the philosophic implication, I just want to link the accepted abstract theory with the classical electromagnetism, nothing more.

Comment: @BenVoigt I never said Maxwell's equations are a good foundation: as all the other branches of the classical physics, they are simply enough refined ways to frame the real world using mathematical models. I am not a physicist and honestly I do not understand your provocation, for I have not denigrated the theory under consideration, but I wished for a link with the classical physics framework (without discussing if such theories are still more or less valid and in what context).

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree with you, engineering models have to fit the reality, it is the definition of model itself: the abstraction is mandatory to address a problem in a smart way. But, for instance, think about the lagrangian mechanics, nobody would study it if it failed to prove its harmony with the Newton-Euler mechanics and if it disclosed as a totally new and self-explanatory theory: if physics already owns a way solid enough (inside the boundary of our macroscopic context) to describe the phenomena related to a certain device, I cannot see how one can simply pretend that it does not exist.

Comment: @Vexx23 Carver's book is a book on quantum mechanics and field spaces, which work for electric fields.  He was working on it with Feynman before Feynman died.  I would read up on Feynman's lectures on physics, vol 3, which is quantum mechanics, as well because Carver Mead writes like his audience is a bunch of Ph.D.s in physics, because it generally is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not completely clear what is being asked and seems to have generated a discussion rather than moving towards a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your difficulty is that the frame of reference or the "space" containing the magnetic flux and force vectors is rotating rather than fixed to points on the structure of the machine. In induction motors, the frame of reference rotates with respect to both the stator and the rotor, moving at the synchronous speed with respect to the stator and at the slip speed with respect to the rotor. In synchronous motors, the frame of reference is fixed with respect to the rotor, but rotates at the synchronous speed with respect to the stator. Thus the vector representations of the fluxes and forces have fixed positions with respect to the phase-vector representations of the AC voltages and currents.

I believe that this representation is developed by first examining the vectors with respect to the windings in the machine without considering the motion of the rotor and then examining the machine operating at a steady-state speed.

Equivalent Circuits

The analysis and control of electric machines makes use of equivalent electric circuits that are mathematically analogous to electromagnetic machines. They have a basis in physics, but that basis may not be as firm and direct as you might like. Engineers generally use the tools that will provide answers with a level of accuracy that is suitable for the ultimate purpose. Scientists strive to explain the laws of nature as thoroughly and accurately as humanly possible. Engineers strive to design products that are useful to human endeavors and economically affordable.

Terminology

Not all engineering terminology is carefully thought out. Even terminology that is carefully created is often simplified in everyday use. As a result, some terminology can have more than one meaning depending on context.  I suspect that engineers are more tolerant of imprecise terminology than scientists may be.

Comment: I have already studied both the machines dynamic model using the most appropriate reference frame, my hesitation rises only when physical vectors such as magnetic field and magnetic flux density, forces and velocities are confused with electromagnetic scalar quantities, namely voltages, currents, induced electromotive forces (motional and transformer ones) and of course, magnetic fluxes and flux linkages.

Comment: I have read also books that do not use this thoughtless approach, preferring to derive the same concepts using applied electromagnetism laws, the same used for studying non rotating electric machines like transformers for instance. 
Anyway, I am very sorry that my question has not been proved enough clear and that you are going to vote to close it, I hoped it could instill a debate among the engineers or the scientists in general.

Comment: This site is not intended for debate. Only questions that are asking for design assistance or help with a question about theory are invited here. There is a chat area http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=electronics.stackexchange.com You need to have 20 reputation points to post there.

Comment: Nevertheless I formulated a question, and answering to questions is not off-topic; its level of clearness is another matter, I would be more than glad to improve it or to add the requested details, but I do not think the question is a void curiosity. Of course, answers aimed just to contest the reasoning without addressing the topic generate only discussions, but my idea of debate was essentially bound to the technical aspects of the problem regarding electric machinery.